# Data Storage Style Binding

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic application with 2 pages. The information from one page (radio buttons) needs to update the text size of another page.
Am i correct in thinking the best way to go about this is to :
store the radio button value in local storage,
call the value in 2nd page from storage, and somehow use this value to update font size?
Any help appreciated.

i have watched tutorials online and this seems to be the only option.

I have the local storage part working correctly (suprisingly) but i am unsure how to update the font of a  tag with this value.

Is a switch statement my next step ?

Comment: Have you tried `NavParams` from `ionic-angular` ?

Comment: thanks  Tharusha , i will look into it,

Comment: Yeah sure! you welcome! @beginner

Comment: Tharusha NavParams is an easier way to pass data from one page to another.Im stuck now using this information to update the font size. Im using ngif. The problem is i have two values to update (title and description.)           <div *ngIf="title=='a'">
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let movie of warMovies"> 
      <a href="{{movie.url}}">
        <ion-thumbnail *ngIf="movie.urlToImage">
          <img src="{{movie.urlToImage}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;">{{movie.title}}</p>
        <p>{{movie.description}}</p>
      </a>
    </ion-item>
   </div>

Comment: it works but only if i select just one radio button value<div *ngIf="Title=='a'"> 
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let movie of warMovies">        
        <p style="font-size: 30px;">{{movie.title}}</p>
        <p>{{movie.description}}</p>
    </ion-item>
   </div>                                                                                                            <div *ngIf="description=='g'"> 
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let movie of warMovies">        
        <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
        <h2 style="font-size: 30px;">{{movie.description}}</h2> 
    </ion-item>  </div>

Comment: It seems you should pass a `Map<>` as a parameter from navparams. Please refer the bellow answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values as a `Map` from home page component

```
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {SecondaryPage} from '../../secondary-page/secondary-page';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
        selector: 'page-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
    }) 
    export class home{

        styleSet:Map<string, string> = Map<string, string>();

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){}

    loadSecondaryPage(){
        //Add data to the styleSet and pass from the navCtrl like below;
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(SecondaryPage, this.styleSet);
      }
    }
```

Get this map from the second page and use it to load your styles

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
        selector: 'page-secondary',
        templateUrl: 'secondary.html',
    }) 
    export class SecondaryPage{

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){
        console.log(navParams.get('ItemNameOne')); //get those values by added key name in the map
        console.log(navParams.get('ItemNameTwo'));        
    }
}
```

You can use `any` datatype as well to replace the `map`